# I'm trying to return the results of one of the if statements, but I am only able to get True/False results?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

```
=IF(OR(AND(C11=1,(B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:B,2,FALSE)))), AND(C11=2,(B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:C,3,FALSE)))),(C11=3,(B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:D,4,FALSE))))), FALSE)
```

Comment: what should be the outcome if it is TRUE ?

Comment: What's wrong? How would we know? What do you expect to happen? What happens, do you get errors?

Comment: I'm trying calculate a date based on various parameters, however I'm only able to get a true/false outcome.  I want the outcome to be one of the vlookups.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide as much information as possible. What is the result, what error do you get, and what exactly do you expect? Do you have sample data so we can test?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below:

```
=IF(C11=1,B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:B,2,FALSE)),IF(C11=2,B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:C,3,FALSE)),"FALSE"))
```

If C11 = 1 it will do `B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:B,2,FALSE))`

If C11 = 2 it will do `B13+3+(VLOOKUP(C15,'Locks and Readers per day'!A:C,3,FALSE))`

If C11 is not equal to 1 or 2, it will return `"FALSE"`

Not sure if this is what you was after or not as the question is not worded the best in all honesty, if I am way off please let me know and I will remove this answer.

Comment: Yes Peter, this is what I am looking for, however I need if C11=3...I think I can figure it out from here though, let me check...

Comment: if you need to add more nested IFs, you will put `IF(C11=3, value if true, value if false)` in place of  `"FALSE"`